# AWS-EC2, how to set multiple public sites with just one instance?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have read many articles and also topics in SF, but could not find out any clue to my case.

I have on instance of AWS-EC2, and want to hold several public sites within it.

I have already get my first public site to run like below:
http://ec2-50-xxx-214-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

What I have done is just added a file which named manmu under
**/etc/apache2/sites-available**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ec2-50-xxx-214-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/manmu/YYYYY/web
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

and then
**ubuntu@ip-10-245-38-136:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ ln -s ../sites-available/manmu**

But how could I get my other sites to run?
For example, I may want some subdomains such as:
http://abc.ec2-50-xxx-214-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
and so on.

Thank you.
Best regards,
tech_me

Comment: you'll have your own domain for that and specify each domain name as apache virtual hosts.

Comment: Take EC2 out of the picture. Virtual hosting is **exactly** the same there as it is on any other linux server.

Comment: @EEAA Thank you. Yes, I am very not familiar with Linux but I still try to configure apache. I could have my local machine to run multiple sites(I mean url) such as: [http://abc.manmu.localhost](http://abc.manmu.localhost), [http://def.manmu.localhost](http://def.manmu.localhost), which I am using **/etc/hosts** and **/etc/apache2/site-availables(and ../site-enabled)**. But I do really not know how to configure AWS for public access of multiple urls.

Comment: @AndreiMikhaltsov Thank you. But I just want to try AWS not to buy any domain now.

Comment: @tech_me - if you want to use name-based virtual hosting, you have two choices. 1) buy a domain or 2) use your hosts file to map names to your server's IP address. With option 2, those names will only be available to your specific workstation, so obviously you'll need to use option 1 if others need access to these sites.

Comment: @tech_me - and also, as I mentioned before, **forget** the fact that you are running on an EC2 instance. The process of standing up name-based virtualhosts is **exactly** the same on EC2 as it is on any other linux server.

Comment: @EEAA Thank you. I think I should choose the 2nd one for my present use. Could you tell me how to configure that? It would be appreciated if there were some example sites.

Comment: I just heard something like **Elastic IP**, does this any help which instead of domain.

Comment: @tech_me - EIPs are irrelevant to this situation. This is a site for professionals, and we expect users to be able to do a bit of their own research. Setting up name virtual hosts and configuring your hosts file are very well-documented here and elsewhere. Just search around...

Comment: @EEAA Thank you time and time again. Yes, I am not the one among the professionals in Linux field. And I also have been searching here and external sites but without result for my case. And I also have been doing something like get my local machine to run multiple sites(urls) as described in this topic but not in AWS. Sorry for pool knowledge, maybe I should post this topic to SO. Anyhow, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create subdomains of the EC2-provided hostname. You must use name-based virtual hosting with *your own* domain name.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHampton. I just heard something like Elastic IP, does this any help which instead of a real domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Name Based Virtual hosting in Apache and can configure multiple websites on single server.

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
  # This first-listed virtual host is also the default for *:80
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com 
  DocumentRoot /www/domain
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName other.example.com
  DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
  </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you. But could you tell me how to write the configuration for url such as [http://ec2-50-xxx-214-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/](http://ec2-50-xxx-214-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/) which is the default url on AWS?